# How to install an Azure Key Vault certificate in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml

Question says it all. I struggled with doing this so I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe people have some suggestions/modifications but here's what we got working with some PowerShell commands.

1. Set up an Azure Resource Manager connection that has permission to access the Key Vault.
   In the Azure portal, you can do this in **"Access policies"** in the Key Vault.
   Give the application Get, List, and Backup permission.
2. In your CI YAML file:

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Install Certificate"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Your Azure Resource Manager connection name>'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    inlineScript: |
      Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
      $vaultName="<Your Key Vault name>"
      $certName="<Your certificate name in the Key Vault>"
      az keyvault secret show --vault-name $vaultName --name $certName | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Expand  value  > certName.pfx
      Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath certName.pfx Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

Comment: Ideally, we should avoid installing certificate. If possible, we should use `Azure Key Vault` task to fetch the secret into variable and access the variable to use the certificate in following tasks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess that would be a little more tricky because our code assumes the certificate is installed when running tests, so I guess we could change our code to look for the certificate in a variable and use it somehow, then we would be writing some code just to make testing easier.